# Random password generator javascript not returning password

Tags: javascript, function, passwords, generator, prompt

I'm new to coding and I can't figure out why my JS isn't generating a random password.  Click ok through the prompts and you will see the issue I am having.  It appears to just be pulling one of my functions in //Generator Functions.  I coded the prompts to be very simple since I still don't quite know what I'm doing.  I just need it to generate the password for this particular exercise.  Any help is appreciated!

```js
// Assignment Code
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Special characters for the function created
const specialCharacters = "!@#$%^&*()";

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.value = password;

}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);

// Prompts that come up after you click generate password
function generatePassword() {
  var passwordLength = prompt("Please enter the number of characters you want for you new password.  It must be more than 12 but less than 128.");

  var numbers = confirm("Do you want numbers in your password?");

  var lowerCases = confirm("Do you want lowercases in your password?");

  var upperCases = confirm("Do you want uppercases in your password?");

  var special = confirm("Do you want special characters in your password?");

  // this is a minimum count for numbers, lowerCases, upperCases & specialCharacters
  var minimumCount = 0;


  // Empty minimums for numbers, lowerCases, upperCases & specialCharacters

  var minimumNumbers = "";
  var minimumLowerCases = "";
  var minimumUpperCases = "";
  var minimumSpecialCharacters = "";


  **// Generator functions**
  var functionArray = [
    function getNumbers() {
      return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 48));
    },

    function getLowerCases() {
      return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26 + 97));
    },

    function getUpperCases() {
      return +String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26 + 65));
    },

    function getSpecialCharacters() {
      return specialCharacters(Math.floor(Math.random() * specialCharacters.length));
    }

  ];

  // Checks to make sure user selected ok for all and uses empty minimums from above

  if (numbers === true) {
    minimumNumbers = functionArray[0];
    minimumCount++;

  }

  if (lowerCases === true) {
    minimumLowerCases = functionArray[1];
    minimumCount++;

  }

  if (upperCases === true) {
    minimumUpperCases = functionArray[2];
    minimumCount++;

  }

  if (special === true) {
    minimumSpecialCharacters = functionArray[3];
    minimumCount++;

  }

  // empty string variable for the for loop below
  var randomPasswordGenerated = "";

  // loop getting random characters
  for (let i = 0; i < (parseInt(passwordLength) - minimumCount); i++) {
    var randomNumberPicked = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

    randomPasswordGenerated += functionArray[randomNumberPicked]();

  }

  // to make sure characters are added to the password
  randomPasswordGenerated += minimumNumbers;
  randomPasswordGenerated += minimumLowerCases;
  randomPasswordGenerated += minimumUpperCases;
  randomPasswordGenerated += minimumSpecialCharacters;


  return randomPasswordGenerated;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Password Generator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>Password Generator</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h2>Generate a Password</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <textarea readonly id="password" placeholder="Your Secure Password" aria-label="Generated Password"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button id="generate" class="btn">Generate Password</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: **Thanks, Aaron!**

Comment: No problem! I wrote new, cleaner code for you to review on that question as well if it is helpful. Cheers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340866/random-password-generator-javascript-not-working/59345948#59345948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I should say you have syntax error with `**// Generator functions**`. I have modified your codes a little bit, compare with mine...

```js
// Special characters for the function created
const specialCharacters = "!@#$%^&*()";
const generateButton = document.getElementById('generateBtn')
generateButton.addEventListener('click', writePassword)

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.value = password;

}

// Prompts that come up after you click generate password
function generatePassword() {
  var passwordLength = prompt("Please enter the number of characters you want for you new password.  It must be more than 12 but less than 128.");

  var numbers = confirm("Do you want numbers in your password?");

  var lowerCases = confirm("Do you want lowercases in your password?");

  var upperCases = confirm("Do you want uppercases in your password?");

  var special = confirm("Do you want special characters in your password?");

  // this is a minimum count for numbers, lowerCases, upperCases & specialCharacters
  var minimumCount = 0;


  // Empty minimums for numbers, lowerCases, upperCases & specialCharacters

  var minimumNumbers = "";
  var minimumLowerCases = "";
  var minimumUpperCases = "";
  var minimumSpecialCharacters = "";


  // Generator functions**
  var functionArray = {
    getNumbers: function() {
      return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 48));
    },

    getLowerCases: function() {
      return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26 + 97));
    },

    getUpperCases: function() {
      return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * 26 + 65));
    },

    getSpecialCharacters: function() {
      return specialCharacters[Math.floor(Math.random() * specialCharacters.length)]
    }

};

  // Checks to make sure user selected ok for all and uses empty minimums from above

  if (numbers === true) {
    minimumNumbers = functionArray.getNumbers();
    minimumCount++;

  }

  if (lowerCases === true) {
    minimumLowerCases = functionArray.getLowerCases();
    minimumCount++;

  }

  if (upperCases === true) {
    minimumUpperCases = functionArray.getUpperCases();
    minimumCount++;

  }

  if (special === true) {
    minimumSpecialCharacters = functionArray.getSpecialCharacters();
    minimumCount++;

  }

  // empty string variable for the for loop below
  var randomPasswordGenerated = "";

  // loop getting random characters
  for (let i = 0; i < (parseInt(passwordLength) - minimumCount); i++) {
    var randomNumberPicked = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

    randomPasswordGenerated += randomNumberPicked;

  }

  // to make sure characters are added to the password
  randomPasswordGenerated += minimumNumbers;
  randomPasswordGenerated += minimumLowerCases;
  randomPasswordGenerated += minimumUpperCases;
  randomPasswordGenerated += minimumSpecialCharacters;


  return randomPasswordGenerated;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>Password Generator</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h2>Generate a Password</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <textarea id="password" placeholder="Your Secure Password" aria-label="Generated Password"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button id="generateBtn" class="btn">Generate Password</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks!  How do I manipulate the code to make it generate at least 12 characters?

Comment: You can add condition after first prompt, then call `writePassword` function inside it, if condition returns `false`